R reshaping the data
data <- data.frame(
  T2_husband = rnorm(5),
  T2_wife = rnorm(5),
  T1_husband = rnorm(5),
  T1_wife = rnorm(5),
  Dyad_ID = 1:5
)

I have 5 columns in the dataset. However, I want to make dataset to have following columns:

Dyad_ID
Role (indicate whetehr this is husband or wife)
My_T1 (T1 score of self)
My_T2 (T2 score of self)
partner_T1 (T2 score of partner, if the row is husband it is wife score. if the row is wife, it is husband score)
partner_T2.


# Reshape the dataset
reshaped_data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(T1_husband, T1_wife, T2_husband, T2_wife), # Columns to reshape
    names_to = c("Time", "Role"),                      # Split column names into "Time" and "Role"
    names_sep = "_"                                    # Separator is "_"
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Dyad_ID, Role), # Keep Dyad_ID and Role as unique identifiers
    names_from = Time,          # Reshape Time into separate columns
    values_from = value         # Values go into "T1" and "T2" columns
  )

# Add My_* and Partner_* columns
reshaped_data <- reshaped_data %>%
  group_by(Dyad_ID) %>% # Group by Dyad_ID to match partner roles
  mutate(
    My_T1 = T1,
    My_T2 = T2,
    Partner_T1 = T1[Role != first(Role)], # Select T1 where Role is not the current Role
    Partner_T2 = T2[Role != first(Role)]  # Select T2 where Role is not the current Role
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # Remove grouping
  select(Dyad_ID, Role, My_T1, My_T2, Partner_T1, Partner_T2)

This is what I tried, but I think it did not work what I intended.

I think you just need to slightly modify how you create Partner_T1 and Partner_T2, the rest of the code is identical to yours
# Reshape the dataset
reshaped_data <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(T1_husband, T1_wife, T2_husband, T2_wife), # Columns to reshape
    names_to = c("Time", "Role"),                      # Split column names into "Time" and "Role"
    names_sep = "_"                                    # Separator is "_"
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Dyad_ID, Role), # Keep Dyad_ID and Role as unique identifiers
    names_from = Time,          # Reshape Time into separate columns
    values_from = value         # Values go into "T1" and "T2" columns
  )


reshaped_data <- reshaped_data %>%
  group_by(Dyad_ID) %>% # Group by Dyad_ID to match partner roles
  mutate(
    My_T1 = T1,
    My_T2 = T2,
    Partner_T1 = ifelse( Role == "husband", T1[Role != first(Role)], T1[Role == first(Role)]), # Select T1 where Role is not the current Role
    Partner_T2 = ifelse( Role == "husband", T2[Role != first(Role)], T2[Role == first(Role)])  # Select T2 where Role is not the current Role
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # Remove grouping
  select(Dyad_ID, Role, My_T1, My_T2, Partner_T1, Partner_T2)


We can manually construct each pair of rows explicitly giving the following compact code:
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  reframe(Role = c("husband", "wife"), 
    My_T1 = pick(starts_with("T1")) %>% unlist,
    My_T2 = pick(starts_with("T2")) %>% unlist,
    Partner_T1 = rev(My_T1),
    Partner_T2 = rev(My_T2),
    .by = Dyad_ID
  )

giving
   Dyad_ID    Role      My_T1       My_T2 Partner_T1  Partner_T2
1        1 husband  1.2240818 -0.56047565  1.7869131  1.71506499
2        1    wife  1.7869131  1.71506499  1.2240818 -0.56047565
3        2 husband  0.3598138 -0.23017749  0.4978505  0.46091621
4        2    wife  0.4978505  0.46091621  0.3598138 -0.23017749
5        3 husband  0.4007715  1.55870831 -1.9666172 -1.26506123
6        3    wife -1.9666172 -1.26506123  0.4007715  1.55870831
7        4 husband  0.1106827  0.07050839  0.7013559 -0.68685285
8        4    wife  0.7013559 -0.68685285  0.1106827  0.07050839
9        5 husband -0.5558411  0.12928774 -0.4727914 -0.44566197
10       5    wife -0.4727914 -0.44566197 -0.5558411  0.12928774

Note
Input used:
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  T2_husband = rnorm(5),
  T2_wife = rnorm(5),
  T1_husband = rnorm(5),
  T1_wife = rnorm(5),
  Dyad_ID = 1:5
)

data
##    T2_husband    T2_wife T1_husband    T1_wife Dyad_ID
## 1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818  1.7869131       1
## 2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  0.4978505       2
## 3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 -1.9666172       3
## 4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  0.7013559       4
## 5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 -0.4727914       5

